# Dropbox: MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type > checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, dropbox, mime-types

my question is half off continuation from [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/90218/accessing-visualforce-static-resources-from-local-machine).

in my page I have:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.dropbox.com/....'>
```

and tried this both get the same error message

```
<script src='https://www.dropbox.com/.....'>
```

error:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://www.dropbox.com/...' because
>   its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type
>   checking is enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess, since you haven't told us what kind of link you're using, but perhaps you're using a "share link" (www.dropbox.com/s/...).

When you get a share link, the link points to a web page that displays the content. To get the raw content, use `?raw=1`. See https://www.dropbox.com/help/201.

Note that this sort of link will require a redirect in the browser, which will slow down your page load. Share links on Dropbox also have bandwidth limits. You may want to, as Limnic suggested, use a hosting service of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has several measures in place to counteract hotlinking like this. Dropbox is not a hosting site. You should find another way; e.g. a free webspace, or a small paid webspace, or Github (allows this with Github pages). And I'm sure there are many other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Preload the script with link tag and as='script'

```
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="https://www.dropbox.com/...fileName.js" />
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload#including_a_mime_type